# Logical-Indexing for Matlab-object-arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, object, indexing

**Is there any way in Matlab R2011b to apply logical-indexing to object-arrays?** The objects which fulfill specific condition(s) regarding their properties should be returned. At best the solution is also possible with object-arrays that are a property of another object (aggregation).

In my project there are a lot of entities which have to be identified by their manifold features. Matlab objects with their properties provide a clear data foundation for this purpose. The alternative of using structs (or cells) and arrays of indices seems to be too confusing. Unfortunately the access to the properties of objects is a little bit complicated.

For Example, all Objects in myArray with Element.val==3 should be returned:

```
elementsValIsThree = myElements(Element.val==3);
```

Best solution so far:

```
find([myElements.val]==3);
```

But this doesn't return the objects and not the absolute index if a subset of myElements is input.

Another attempt returns only the first Element and needs constant properties:

```
myElements(Element.val==3);
```

A minimal example with class definition etc. for clarification:

```
% element.m
classdef Element
    properties
        val
    end
    methods
        function obj = Element(value)
            if nargin > 0 % to allow empty construction
                obj.val = value;
            end
        end
    end   
end
```

Create array of Element-Objects:

```
myElements(4) = Element(3)
```

Now `myElements(4)` has `val=3`.

Comment: What about 

`myElements(1) = Element(3); myElements(2) = Element(5); myElements([myElements.val] == 3)`?

Comment: Easy and beautiful solution! When you post it as an answer I can mark the question solved.

Comment: Well not so fast, the problem with @OlegKomarov solution is that it needs all properties to have non-empty values...

Comment: This is indeed true, however knowing that the user wants to take advantage of logical indexing, I'd suggest to initialize the properties to a default (which could be NaN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but the logical index can be generated as

```
arrayfun(@(e) isequal(e.val,3), myElements);
```

So, to pick the elements of `myElements` whose `val` field equals `3`:

```
elementsValIsThree = myElements(arrayfun(@(e) isequal(e.val,3), myElements));
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This is exactly the right answer - and a motivation to finally learn about arrayfun and the @ handle.

Comment: Those functions that take function handles as a arguments (`arrayfun`, `bsxfun` etc) are very powerful indeed

Comment: Arrayfun is just a concealed loop.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Sure. But `myElements(arrayfun(@(e) isequal(e.val,3), myElements))` is easier to read than the equivalent loop... once you get used, at least :-)

Comment: Easier?

    `N   = numel(myElements);
    idx = false(N,1);
    for ii = 1:N
        idx(ii) = myElements(ii).Val == 3;
    end`

A loop is verbose, maybe a more unnecessary syntax, as compared to arrayfun, but the core operation is immediately clear as opposed to `@()`. It's also likely to be faster.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Yes, a loop is usually faster